# Operator norm directly from phase space representation of photonic quantum operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, optics, research-level, quantum-information, wigner-transform

I'm interested in calculating the operator norm of a Hermitian operator, say $B$, acting on the Hilbert space of square integrable functions.  The context is I have an optical system in all its infinite dimensional glory.  To be clear, by operator norm I mean the largest eigenvalue, or
$||B||_{\infty}=\sup \{ \langle \psi \vert B \vert \psi \rangle | \langle \psi \vert \psi \rangle =1  \}$.

I have a neat expression for $B$ in terms of its Characteristic function / Wigner function.  My question is whether anyone knows a neat and easy way of calculating the operator norm within the phase space picture.  Of course, I could truncate the operator to small Fock numbers (assuming that this is a good approximation), work out the matrix in the Fock basis and crunch the numbers.  However, I'm just curious whether there is a more elegant solution.  I have in mind such equalities as $tr ( A ) = \int W_{A}(r) dr $ and $tr ( A^{\dagger} B ) = \pi \int W_{A}(r)W_{B}(r)dr$, which give a useful correspondence between Wigner functions and the operators themselves.... are these any such expressions for norms?

Being pessimistic I guess the answer might simply be NO!  However, I thought it would be worth consulting the collective wisdom of TPSE.

Comment: For sure you have $||B||_{\infty} \leq \pi \ \sup_{r} |W_B(r)|$.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I did actually spot that bound myself after I posted, but I would want something much tighter. e.g. tight enough to give the right answer for a thermal Gaussian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not an complete answer, but (hopefully) it may help:
$$\text{tr} \left( A B \right) = \pi \int W_A(r) W_B(r) dr = \pi \int P_A(r) Q_B(r) dr,$$
where $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint operators, $r=(p,q)$ is a point of the phase space, $W(r)$ is a Winger function, $P(r)$ - [Glauber-Sudarshan P-representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glauber%E2%80%93Sudarshan_P-representation) and  $Q(r)$ - a [Husimi Q representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husimi_Q_representation).

The second equality holds, as $Q(r)$ is a Gaussian-smeared $W(r)$, and $P(r)$ is a Gaussian-sharpened $W(r)$ (to see it explicitly, use the [convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)).

Then you can use advantages of each of the mentioned representations:

- $P_A(r)$: is sometimes easier to handle than its Wigner counterpart,
- $Q_B(r)$: is easily obtainable numerically (or sometimes - even analytically) from $W_B(r)$; for a non-negatively definite operator it is nonnegative, i.e. $Q_B(r) \geq 0$.

In particular for $P_A(r)\geq 0$ and $Q_B(r)\geq 0$  one gets a bound
$$ \int P_A(r) Q_B(r) dr \leq \left( \sup_r\ Q_b(r) \right) \int P_A(r)dr = \sup_r\ Q_b(r).$$
In other words, when one restricts to finding maximum over a mixture of coherent states, then $\pi\ \sup_r\ Q_b(r)$ is the upper bound, which is tight.

However, the state achieving maximum need not to be coherent, so in general one gets 
$$||B||_\infty \geq \pi\ \sup_\alpha \langle \alpha | B | \alpha \rangle = \pi \ \sup_r\ Q_B(r).$$

Additionally, for some applications it may help that:
$$\sup_r\ Q_B(r)\leq \sup_r\ W_B(r)\leq \sup_r\ |W_B(r)|.$$

Comment: Thanks for your great answer.  I didn't think to use the Husimi Q representation, but it seems to give quite a good bound! Though the bound is not always tight, it is tight for some important cases.  For example, your bound would be tight for a thermal Gaussian, and displacements of a thermal Gaussian.  I think this might be tight enough to be useful to me.

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite sure I understand why this is an upper bound on $||B||_{\infty}$ and not lower, and why there isn't a $\pi$ involved. So, via wikipedia, we have a $Q$ function:  $Q_{B}(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\pi} \langle \alpha \vert B \vert \alpha \rangle $.  Taking the sup gives, $\sup_{\alpha} Q_{B} ( \alpha ) = \sup_{\alpha} \langle \alpha \vert B \vert \alpha \rangle / \pi \leq  \sup_{\psi} \langle \psi \vert B \vert \psi \rangle / \pi = ||B||_{\infty} / \pi$.  Have I misunderstood something here?

Comment: @Earl: Haste makes waste - sorry for my omission. I lost $\pi$ and it wasn't on purpose. When it comes to the inequality (this one with $||B||_\infty$) - now I see it is not right. I wanted to use $\int P(r) Q(r) dr \leq \int P(r) (\sup_{R} Q(R)) dr$ but I've forgotten that $P(r)$ is not positive. I am fixing my post in a sec.

Comment: Cool.  But maybe we can also have both bounds such that $\pi \sup_{r} |Q_{B}(r)| \leq ||B||_{\infty} \leq \pi \sup_{r} |P_{B}(r)|$.  For the following reason. $||B||_{\infty} = \pi | \sup_{\psi} \int P_{B}(r) Q_{\psi}(r) dr | \leq \sup_{\psi} \int | P_{B}(r) |.| Q_{\psi}(r) | dr $, where $Q_{\psi}$ is for some $\vert \psi \rangle$. Which is simply $||B||_{\infty} \leq \pi (\sup_{r}|P(r)|)(\int |Q_{\psi}|(r))$, but since Q is positive and integrates to 1, we have $||B||_{\infty}\leq \pi \sup_{r}|P(r)| $.  This gives the other bound, which happens to be the one I prefer to have.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, as I think the Wigner function gives a better upper bound than the P-function.

Comment: Greetings, I would like to thank you for this response It is 11 years old but as you can tell, it is relevant even today. I have one question, I have been trying to reproduce the second line of your post where you show an alternative way to compute the trace $Tr\{AB\}$. You say that the convolution theorem is the tool necessary for the proof of such a result. I have struggled with arriving at the same conclusion. Is there any chance that you could present a proof of this result within your response. I can share with you my result if you'd like to see it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

In the case when $B$ is a compact operator, a limiting process can be applied to get the operator's norm to any arbitrarily small precision. 
This process is a Hilbert space generalization of the linear algebra relation for a Hermitian matrix $A$.

$ ||A||_{\infty} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|tr(A^n)|^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

For the data given in the question the operator composition is to be performed by means of the star product:

$ W_{AB}(r) =(W_A \star W_B)(r) =\int W_A(r_1)W_B(r_2) k(r, r_1, r_2) dr$

Thus one needs to know the star product kernel $k$. 
(Of course, in the ordinary phase space case, the star product is the Moyal star product).

Thus formally for the operator case:

$ ||B||_{\infty} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|tr(\star^{n} B)|^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

The limit exists when $B$ is compact.

Comment: A small tweak in the transcription of Cayley's method: $ ||B||_{\infty} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|\int dr (\star B)^{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}$.  It may be easier to parse out this way.

Comment: Actually, the abs value in the above power iteration algorithm produces the *spectral radius*, but it is assumed the reader appreciates the trivial connection to the norm sought.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Thank you for your remarks Prof. Zachos. It is a great pleasure to have you on physics S.E.

Comment: Thanks. Actually a practical and instructive illustration of this method is using [the Weyl transform of a Gaussian of operators][1] to compute the norm of the bounded Boltzmann operator $B\equiv\exp(-\frac{\hat{p}^2+\hat{x}^2}{2kT})$.


  [1]: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113604/examples-of-weyl-transforms-of-nontrivial-operators/206262#206262

Answer (score 1):

There is an obvious property of the Wigner function when one takes the limit $p\rightarrow\infty$. By the Riemann's lemma, *the Wigner function is expected to go to zero in this limit but it does driven by the largest eigenvalue*. Your question can be stated in the following way. The Wigner function for a generic operator $A$ can be defined as

$$ W_A(x,p)=\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dy e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}py}\langle x-y|A|x+y\rangle. $$

Now, assume that you have diagonalized $A$ so that $A|a_n\rangle=a_n|a_n\rangle$, you can write immediately

$$W_A(x,p)=\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\sum_n a_n\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dy e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}py}\phi_n^*(x-y)\phi_n(x+y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\sum_n a_n W_n(x,p) $$

being $\phi_n(x)=\langle a_n|x\rangle$. Of course, if the spectrum of $A$ will not run to infinity, taking the limit of increasing $p$ should grant the work done. This can also be argued from the unbounded case of the Hamiltonian of the harmonic oscillator. In this case you will get

$$W_A(x,p)=\sum_n E_n W_n^{H.O.}(x,p)$$

being now

$$ W_n^{H.O.}(x,p)=\frac{(-1)^n}{\pi\hbar}e^{-\frac{p^2}{\hbar^2\kappa^2}-\kappa^2x^2}L_n\left(2\frac{p^2}{\hbar^2\kappa^2}+2\kappa^2x^2\right)$$

and $L_n(x)$ the Laguerre polynomials and $\kappa^2=m\omega/\hbar$. In the limit $p\rightarrow\infty$, being $x$ fixed, the Laguerre polynomial will give the driving contribution $p^n$. In this particular case, it is the "energy" of the oscillator to drive to zero with the power of $n$.